# How to get the tbody element of a table using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a table structure (Table1) with thead and tbody.

My main thead also has a table inside with its own thead and tbody.

When I use `$('#Table1 tbody')` it returns all tbody elements whereas I'd only need the tbody of the Table1.

How could this be achieved?

Thanks,

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
 $('#Table1 > tbody')
```

`>` will get direct children.

Comment: Note the quotes are outside the whole expression, and not around each element selector, as it can be seen elsewhere. Saved my day, thx !

Answer (score 29):

Alternative:

```
 $('#Table1').children('tbody')
```

Answer (score 0):

simple add table id and get the value
**example**

```
 $('#dc-table tbody').on('keyup','.qty_approved', function(){
   alert('tested...');   
 });
```