# jQuery - element.on click for match cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an element that is inside a table somewhere.
I need to get his tbody element.

How can I do that?

Tried `$(this).closest('tbody')`

But it looks like it did not work..

My code:

```
$("table").on('click', ['td'], function(event) {

    if ($(this).hasClass('uneditable')) { return; }
    // here I need to check the tbody element
    console.log($(this).closest("tbody"))
    }
```

Maybe I am doing this wrong, because I want to apply this function only if a click on a table with specific classes for elements:

- table - `dattable`
- tbody - `editabe`
- td - not `uneditable`

Thanks !

Comment: Can you provide a working example?

Comment: Just added.....

Comment: Check this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763006/how-to-get-the-tbody-element-of-a-table-using-jquery

Comment: Don't put the brackets around `'td'`.

Comment: I need get parent from child not child from parent

Comment: Replace `['td'] != td`

Comment: Please look the last edit under the code section

Comment: Can you try this $(this).children("tbody")? You'll need to use children since $(this) will refer to table and not td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just bind click to the tbody that has the class and check the class on click.

```
$("table.dattable tbody.editable").on("click", "td:not(.uneditable)", function(){});
```

Or id the .editable is dynamic on the table than move it to the other selector

```
$("table.dattable").on("click", "tbody.editable td:not(.uneditable)", function(){});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `$("table").on('click', 'td',` and **not** `$("table").on('click', ['td'],`

```js
console.log($('#a1').closest('tbody').length)

$("table").on('click', 'td', function(event) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('uneditable')) { return; }
  // here I need to check the tbody element
  console.log($(this).closest("tbody").length)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div id="a1">asdf</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

By using `['td']` - `this` is a reference to the `table` (and not the cell - `td`), so you can't use the `closest` to find the `tbody` element.

### update

If you want to select only `td`s that **dont** have a specific class you can use the `:not` pseudo-class:

```js
$("table").on('click', 'td:not(.uneditable)', function(event) {
  console.log($(this).closest("tbody").length)
});
```

```css
.uneditable {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="t"><div>asdf</div></td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td class="uneditable"><div>asdf</div></td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td class="t"><div>asdf</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice, I did not know that.
But is there a better way to check the click that match the cases as I mentioned after the code snippet?

Comment: Thanks, But I need the `on` function to be applied just if the `tbody` has `editable` class and the table itself has `datatable` class

Comment: so use the relevant selector: `$('table.datatable tbody.editable')`

Comment: That is impossible in my case for the `tbody` because Im using `datatable` with paging and on any paging a new tbody is rendered.
Thats why I need to check the tbody inside the `on` function

Comment: So put the `tbody.editable` inside the `on` function (same way you do with the `td`). BTW - if you asked exactly that you would get the answer much faster :) `$('table.datatable').on('click', 'tbody.editable td' `

Answer (score 0):

Use `:not()`

```
$("table").on('click', 'td:not(".uneditable")', function(event) {

});
```

FYI, don't forget to replace `['td']` with `td`

```js
console.log($('#a1').closest('tbody').length)
$("table.datatable").on('click', 'td:not(".uneditable")', function(event) {
  console.log($(this).closest("tbody.editable").length)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>1st table</h1>
<table class="datatable">
  <tbody class="editable">
  <tr>
    <td class="uneditable"><div id="a1">ABC</div></td>
    <td class="uneditable"><div id="a1">XYZ</div></td>
    <td><div id="a1">PQR</div></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h1>2nd table</h1>
<table class="datatableNot">
  <tbody class="editable">
  <tr>
    <td class="uneditable"><div id="a1">ABC</div></td>
    <td class="uneditable"><div id="a1">XYZ</div></td>
    <td><div id="a1">PQR</div></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I need to verify that table has `datatable` class and the tbody has `editrable`   class too

Comment: @OzBar-Shalom : check my updated snippet. you will get the idea of working code.

Comment: Code will be working for `1st table and PQR` only as per your need.